# Mock a super class method Mockito test cases

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, superclass

I have a structure like

```
class A{
 public String  mymethod(){
     //Some processing here
 }
}
class B extends A{
  public void mySomeMethod(){
     String myToken = super.myMethod();
     //processing
  }
}
```

Now i want to mock the call mentioned here String myToken = super.myMethod();
and return a constant String in my test class. 
I tried doing

```
Mockito.doReturn("gdgwdgweg23et287").when((A)bSpy).myMethod();
```

But this isnt helping as the method is still getting called.
Can anyone suggest an approach here

Comment: Out of interest, *why* are you trying to mock this out? If `mymethod` calls into some other dependency, can you mock that out instead?

Comment: unit test case should have its scope limited to that particular method & i am trying to avoid any external method call. the method above is trying to generate some token based on some logic which is my case & i am trying to avoid that, which IMO is perfectly ok. The question here is not whether i am out of interest or not the question is how to mock a method which is invoked using super, had this method being abstract and its implementaton been in class B i could have mocked it easily but since the implementation of this method is gonna be common across various classes i did it like this.

Comment: I would suggest being pragmatic rather than dogmatic. The idea that a unit test shouldn't end up calling *any* code other than the method it's trying to be testing is rarely valid in reality - would you want to avoid calling `String` methods, mocking out `substring` etc? If you *really* want to keep going down this path (and I would recommend that you don't) then I'd *expect* it to be feasible with code such as you've already posted - after all, the method isn't `final`. It would help if you'd post a *complete* example of both the production code and the test, so that we can reproduce it.

Answer (score 2):

The reason the real method is still being called is that the spy is just a wrapper around the spied object. Once method invocation is inside that wrapper boundary, the wrapper (spy) is not involved. More to the point, you can't stub methods where the spied object calls itself. This is because the call is already inside the wrapper (spy) boundary.

If you call `myMethod` on the spy, you will get the stubbed version. But if you call `mySomeMethod` on the spy, there is no stub here so it passes the call onto the `B` instance which calls in actuality `this.myMethod`.

Answer (score 0):

First you don't need to cast instance of B to A, casting won't work here anyway.
Then my second question would be - how you create bSpy object ?

Comment: bSpy is created like Mockito.spy(new B())